# Does a finite morphism to $\mathbb{P}^n$ necessarily split at some height one point in the etale locus?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does there exist a finite morphism $\pi\colon X\to \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$, that does not admit a rational section along any prime divisor $D\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ in the locus where $\pi$ is etale?

Comment: Small comment: do you want $\pi$ to be finite *surjective*?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Ah yes, I was thinking of an etale cover of the complement of divisors on $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Do you think that there is anything special about $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$? Or could this hold for an arbitrary base variety?

Comment: @DanielLoughran Thanks for clarification! I think $\mathbb{P}^n$ is special because it has Picard rank $1$, and Lefschetz holds for $Pic$, (I was thinking if one could find a counterexample using torsion line bundles and the surjective map $H^1(\mu_n0)\to Pic(U)[n]$, but it turned out we can always find some irreducible polynomial of the form $g+l^{\mathrm{deg}(g)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite surjective morphism of smooth (projective) varieties over complex numbers. Let $B\subset Y$ be the branch locus and let $q\in Y-B$. Let $f^{-1}(q)=\{p=p_1,\ldots, p_n\}$, where $n=\deg f$. Take $D\subset X$, a smooth divisor passing through $p$, but not passing through $p_i, i>1$. Let $E=f(D)$. Then, one can check that $E$ is smooth at $q$ and $f:D\to E$ is birational. This gives on an open set of $E$ the section you desire (or not desire, as the question is framed).